# Signing App Error with Android Wear

Tags: android, android-studio, wear-os

I know that there are already several android signing questions on Stack Overflow, but I haven't found any having to do with the Android Wear. I am following the steps to sign my app here: http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html. My phone app gradle file has `wearApp project(':myWearApp')` in its dependencies. When I go to Build/Generate Signed APK... and try to generate the APK for my phone app, I get the following error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':myWearApp:packageRelease'.
> Failed to read key from keystore
```

Does anyone have a clue on how to fix this? I can successfully create an APK for the Wear app I have, but not for the phone app which depends on the Wear app. I have a separate keystore for the phone and wear (not sure if that matters).

Answer (score 0):

Both apps (wear and phone) should be signed with the same exact key otherwise they won't be able to talk to each other.

Comment: Good to know :) I am now trying to use the same key as the phone, but there is the same error. I've done some more digging in the mean time and I think I have the wrong alias. So now I'm trying to figure out how to do that through the command line

Comment: I've got it resolved now. I found out the correct alias. Thanks again for the tip on using one key.